# If Jon Skeet never used Stack Overflow again, how long until he gets less than 200 rep in a day?

Tags: discussion, specific-user

It seems clear he is capped at 200 rep based on votes on old answers, and so without posting any new content he would still get at least 200 rep every day for some time.

However it also seems that as a question gets older the rate of upvotes reduces, or am I wrong on this?

Some data modeling should be able to show at what point (if any) the rate of upvotes will reduce to below 20 a day, assuming he makes no new posts.
Also apart from bounties, if Jon Skeet stops using Stack Overflow, is it possible for anyone to ever overtake his rep? (If so, how long would it take?)

(Clearly if everyone stops using C# and Java there will be a big drop-off, but assume for this question that their usage only declines at a steady rate.)

Comment: If Jon Skeet never used Stack Overflow, he'll still be the top rated user.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, but for how many years....

Comment: I've wondered this myself. Would be very interested to see analysis. It's worth considering weekdays very separately from weekends, btw.

Comment: [Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) stopped all activity between December 2010 and September 2013 - you can try to extrapolate from that... [Here is the tail end of that period](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=26) (at the time of posting this comment)

Comment: Absentee replords FTW

Comment: Related: [Does Jon Skeet ever have to answer another question to remain the #1 user on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198277/does-jon-skeet-ever-have-to-answer-another-question-to-remain-the-1-user-on-sta)

Comment: Easy, just downvote him at 11:59pm UTC on a day he doesn't get any accepts. And if he stops posting, there's only a limited number of "passive" accepts he can receive.

Comment: @Mysticial: with a number of sock puppets, we can crack him down to 0.

Comment: Could it happen due to reversing of serial upvoting?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have started with creating sockpuppets right away. I should have enough sockpuppets in a couple of years with enough dedication! #Theywillneversuspect

Comment: Should be asked on [math.se] or [MO] :p

Comment: Well he would continue to gain points obviously, but in a few years I'm quite sure some of the other guys in the top 10 would pass him if Jon did nothing.   StackOverflow has been so awesome.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I wholeheartedly support knocking him down to 0, let us begin >:)

Comment: @Oded August 16th was an off day during Alex's off days.

Comment: We'd all lose our rep from downvotes and not have enough rep to downvote him before he hit zero. @StevenPenny

Comment: Stack Overflow is trying to improve its reputation with Jon Skeet.

Comment: How much rep would Jon Skeet have if daily rep were not capped?

Comment: The real question is, does Jon Skeet ever need to use a bidet again as long as SO is online?

Comment: @Boann: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34000; the query claims 3116147 at the moment... I've no idea whether or not that's accurate, but it sounds *plausible* to me. (It looks like it doesn't include bounties, but I haven't had enough of those to affect it more than a percent or two...)

Comment: Note that the last time Jon Skeet didn't get 200 rep in a day was earlier this year. I feel rather confident, therefore, assuming that it would not take very long to stop earning 200 every day, and not much longer to stop earning 200 even the majority of days.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Really? When was that? I thought it was 2010, although it's a while since I've checked.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's been at least a month since I checked, but as far as I remember it was back in March or so. It was rather surprising.

Comment: It was on [April 10th](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=6), apparently due to... an unaccept after breaking the rep cap? Looks strange to me.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: My reputation audit for that day shows 200 - and there are *plenty* of capped votes there, so I don't know what's going on for sure. I think the unaccept probably just nullifies the accept in the rep audit (so both are removed), whereas in the profile view it lists both the +15 and the -15. According to the rep audit, the last sub-200 day was June 6th 2010.

Comment: @Jon, that would make a good meta-question. Maybe all the bugs in the reputation system were not ironed out after all.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I'm not sure it's so much "broken", as "showing something different".

Comment: @Jon, are you also seeing 185 for that day on your side? If so, the issue is not related to something others aren't supposed to see, and I would call that an interesting, possibly UI, bug.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I see 185 in the profile view, but 200 for http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: We really need a jon-skeet tag soon.

Comment: If @JonSkeet goes missing tomorrow, we'll know where to look.

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't use SO; SO uses Jon Skeet.

Comment: That's why he's known as the Chuck Norris of Programmers.

Comment: Um, what is going on.

Comment: @JamesBoutcher what part don't you get?

Comment: We've had a rainbow logo, and a temporary change to Stackoverfloooooow.  Why not just follow the well-forged path and rename the site "SkeetOverflow" on the man's birthday each year?

Comment: @dazedandconfused that would actually make a great April Fool's joke. You hear me @Oded? *Make it happen*.

Comment: Closed for #NoFunAllowed  :-)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Really? When has Jon Skeet ever solved a programming problem with a roundhouse kick?

Comment: @Machavity Jon Skeet doesn't need to beat up problems, problems surrender when they realize they're going up against Jon Skeet. #Skeet4Prez2016

Comment: @danradu: Jon Skeet doesn't use SO. Jon Skeet and SO are one.

Answer (score 75):

There are a few other issues at play here.

## Long-Tail Usefulness Effect

Jon Skeet's answers will continue to be useful in his absence, and will thus continue to be upvoted for quite some time. Even if they cease being useful, they will have become accepted as the standard for how the languages he describes actually work, and the languages will be considered wrong if they change to invalidate his answers.

## Long-Tail Exemplar Effect

Even if Jon Skeet's answers cease to be correct, his sheer personality and the quality of his posts will live on and inspire others to attempt to imitate them, and will probably elicit a few upvotes (at least until the time they are archived).

## Jon Skeet Effect (aka Alex Martelli effect)

If Jon Skeet ever stops using Stack Overflow, his sheer forward momentum will cause him to return inadvertently. Even if he dies, his spirit will live on, continuing to haunt Stack Overflow and provide thorough, detailed answers about .NET and Java by sheer force of will.

Comment: Okay, enough ass-kissing. Back to the Review Queues for me.

Comment: [Jon skeet is the only person who can pass Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues)

Comment: "the languages will be considered wrong if they change to invalidate his answers."  I sense a need for some jokes here, on the order of Chuck Norris gags.  Such as "Compilers don't issue warnings to Jon Skeet; Jon Skeet issues warnings to compilers."

Comment: @Prune There's already [a question about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: Got it; just what I wanted!  ... and it already contains all seven of the ones I wrote in the interim.  :-)

Comment: This guy is a legend.

Comment: @James_Parsons - but he still hasn't made the jump to god yet. See [The Church Of Unlimited Devotion](http://articles.sun-sentinel.com/1992-01-18/features/9201030888_1_dennis-mcnally-jerry-garcia-sect).