# Who's the person with more answers than Jon Skeet? When will they catch him in rep terms?

Tags: discussion, reputation, top-users, specific-user

Someone is working hard to usurp SO's [first millionaire](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=jon-skeet-milestone). They've already exceeded Mr. Skeet for number of questions answered, so who is it, and when (if ever) will they catch up in terms of rep?

[image]

Comment: I do not think is not really on topic for meta, but that user is probably [gordon-linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

Comment: I had a bit of a look myself https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow and I guess it could be @jezrael - if you assume rep is roughly area under the curve - there will probably be quite a few users with higher rep than this "shooting star" user.

Comment: @AndrewM The rep cap means that reputation and number of answers is entirely uncoorelated after a certain point, and that's even assuming that the answers are *good* answers attracting upvotes (which *does*, in practice, tend to result in correlation for active users not regularly rep capping, because users constantly posting bad answers tend to get banned).

Comment: @Servy - which would further suggest that older users have more rep - and this (new looking) user will not be at the top of reputation tables. (so probably not gordon-linoff)

Comment: The Y axis represents number of cumulative answers. Pretty sure that line is the user I said earlier. Reading the graph properly and a bit of playing with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/785424) would have been enough to avoid making this question.

Comment: @AndrewM "which would further suggest that older users have more rep", no, not quite.  *Among users that are consistently hitting the rep cap*, older users will tend to have more rep (there can still be differences due to bounties and accepted answers, but there is approximate correlation in that situation).  Note that "users consistently hitting the rep cap" is a *very* small percentage of users.

Comment: Good point. Although a user with 40k plus answers (assuming they're quality) is likely to be among that select group. Although I just had the horrible notion that it might be the Community Moderator user?

Comment: No, the Community bot has many, many more answers. It owns 163825 answers. So the bots are winning. Again.

Comment: @AndrewM Sure, you can say that, "the older of these two users will have more rep" because those two users are going to be consistently hitting the rep cap.  But you can't say that in general that older users will have more rep, because there are *lots* of old users earning no rep these days.

Comment: Yup. My theory is that the curve below Jon-Skeets that follows a similar profile, but started in 2008/9 is likely to have higher rep than the anomaly user, who appears to have only started in 2013. Gordon-linoff is a good candidate - but he might have _too much_ rep to be this user.

Comment: Andrew, there is not a lot of doubt about it. If you follow the query I've shown you earlier, you'll see there are no other users with that amount of answers.

Comment: OK - @Yivi's query has solved it - it is gordon-linoff. If that was an answer it would get accepted. (I know you don't think this is a good question - but that _would_ be a good answer to a bad question)

Comment: @yivi why wouldn't it be on-topic? I give you that it might not be well researched or is useful but I don't see why it couldn't fit here.

Comment: @rene It might be, my bad if it is. But I do not think this is a question about so or the software that powers so, but about one of its users. No harm done anyway.

Comment: @rene Also, no freehand arrows.

Comment: @yivi  Also, completely out of place here on meta.

Comment: As that other user's curve seems to go up at about the time Jon Skeet's answer rate slopes down, I'd suggest this is a sock puppet account of Jon Skeet himself.

Comment: Jon Skeet's 1 million achievement has been slightly mitigated by the fact that they could only proclaim he has the _second_ most number of answers on the site.

Comment: Given this question perhaps the # of x (questions/answers etc) would be interesting metrics to be exposed at an easily discovered level - such as overall Rep is.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

It's [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff). The simplest way of guessing an eventual rep crossover is to look at the rep from 2017 via the [Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01).

In 2017, I received 78,908 rep, and Gordon received 129,388 - a difference of 50,480.

I'm currently 372,272 ahead, which would suggest that Gordon will overtake me in a bit over 7 years... *if* we both keep the same reputation rates.

Comment: Roughly between 6 to 8 years ...

Comment: Another author. I'm curious what kind of relationship there is between being an author and engaging with your audience via sites like SO. Which drives the other? Did writing a book make you feel more compelled to help devs out online, or did helping devs online drive you toward writing a book (and blogs, etc)?

Comment: @JDB: Well it suggests someone who cares about effective communication and education, for one thing.

Comment: This man, [he does not sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=answers). There is an 8 hour gap in the timestamps for the last day, but it looks like he spends **every waking minute** answering SQL questions.

Comment: ...or it's just another form of addiction.....

Comment: Suspicious linearity, looks like roughly 22 answers a day, for 5 years. Are we sure it's a real person and not just a basement full of enslaved SQL devs at MS? It could be a cry for help. :-)

Comment: Uh oh, a new Stack Overflow user is being prepped for meme-ing :)

Comment: Do you know Gordon Linoff personally? Do you have chatted with him ?

Comment: [That Gordon Linoff?](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=Gordon+S.+Linoff&search-alias=books&field-author=Gordon+S.+Linoff&sort=relevancerank)

Comment: And *if* trends in tech don't sway one way or the other, affecting the usefulness of already written answers...

Comment: @Holger In his SO profile, Gordon Linoff has a link to a book on Amazon. When clicking that link, and then inside Amazon on the author, you'll get the list you've linked to, so I guess unless there are two database experts named Gordon Linoff, that's the same person.

Comment: I don't understand how either of you could receive more than 71200 (365*200).  Given that you reach the rep-cap nearly every day, I think you are uncatchable (unless SO starts counting rep from old answers less).

Comment: @MartinBonner You get +15 for an accepted answer whether you hit the rep cap or not, and there are also bounties. So: possible, but very hard.

Comment: @MartinBonner - if you glance at Gordon's reputation tab for the last 7 days you see daily totals of 325, 410, 350, 440, 520, 380, 290

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I noticed that after posting the comment. Doing it the other way round would have been too simple...

Comment: Here is a little back story from Gordon's blog about his growing interest with Stack Overflow. He talks a bit about his routine and how he came to answer so many questions at a very fast rate. 
http://blog.data-miners.com/2014/08/an-achievement-on-stack-overflow.html

Comment: SO should improve rep display for millions. 1008k (Jon's current rep) is ugly.

Comment: Nah if you post more answers and answers you still might surpass Gordon Linoff's answers.

Comment: I noticed that Gordon is getting very close to 1 million now - so might be a bit ahead of that schedule as "only" 203K behind

Comment: Prediction seems to be holding on.

Answer (score 37):

The user with more answers than Jon Skeet is most likely [**Gordon Linoff**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), with 41,119 answers at the time of writing.

I looked a number of other user profiles but could not find anybody else with more answers than Jon Skeet. See, for example,

- [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov): 21,497
- [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava): 20,756 answers
- [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware): 20,134 answers

Here are a number of other heavy hitters:

- [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc): 18,588 answers
- [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters): 18,073 answers
- [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin): 17,408 answers
- [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc): 17,010 answers
- [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar): 16,895 answers
- [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant): 16,040 answers
- [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight): 15,112 answers
- [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder): 14,943 answers
- [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks): 14,918 answers
- [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell): 14,133 answers
- [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet): 13,129 answers
- [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey): 13,006 answers
- [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun): 12,706 answers
- [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan): 12,280 answers
- [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams): 12,209 answers
- [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c): 11,860 answers
- [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman): 10,614 answers
- [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa): 10,641 answers
- [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler): 11,609 answers

Consider this post as an informal **hall of fame** for some of the most productive contributors on this site ;-)

I'm not going to guess how long it would take for Gordon Linoff or anybody else to catch up with Jon Skeet. This reminds me of the question [If Jon Skeet never used Stack Overflow again, how long until he gets less than 200 rep in a day?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307024/6002174) (rep cap was mentioned in some of the comments here), which was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 21):

Using SEDE you could easily put together [a query to find the user with most answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785478/top-answerer). It is indeed [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), as the other answerers here assumed.

Comment: Jon Skeet does not assume

Comment: [Today I learned I'm 966th in the list of top answerers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785496/top-1000-answerers)! (and you are 71...)

Comment: Nice. @yivi did the same - but was too modest to post an answer, and it got lost in the comments. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785494/answers-per-user

Comment: @DavidG now you're at 959th.

Comment: @AsifAli72090 I clearly need to answer more questions!

Answer (score 0):

There's an [ongoing Meta Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198277/does-jon-skeet-ever-have-to-answer-another-question-to-remain-the-1-user-on-sta/270693#270693) on when (if ever) Jon Skeet will be overtaken as #1 in rep.

The short answer is "probably never".

The slightly longer answer is "If Gordon Linoff can maintain this frankly amazing pace, AND Jon stops answering new questions completely, still the best part of a decade".

Comment: Nov 2023 is the estimate here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400528/73226

Comment: I mean, that would still be 5 years and 10 months since I posted this, so I'm going to call that technically correct :)