# Congratulations for reaching a million, Gordon Linoff!

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, top-users

I just noticed that Gordon Linoff reached today, August 20, 2020, a million points of reputation:

[image: profile for Gordon Linoff on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

This comes after an astonishing amount of 71,839 answers (and 0 questions!). He only joined in 2012, so that's an average of ~22.8 answers per day, every day, for the last 3144 days.To put perspective on the numbers, the second answerer on the site is [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (our [first millionaire](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/)) with 35K answers and then several others with 20k+ ([reference](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785478/top-answerers)).

I think I haven't had the chance to have Gordon answer one of my questions, but I have definitely used his answers to others.

So: thanks, congratulations and keep up with the great job!

Comment: Quite the feat indeed!

Comment: WOW! I was kinda waiting for this meta post, because it would be unfair if he didn't get a party like Jon Skeet did.

Comment: _"the second ... is Jon Skeet"_ **HOW DARE YOU?!**  In all seriousness though, congratulations to Gordon! What a great achievement!

Comment: Hey folks, let's keep this focused on the achievement, and not discuss other matters here in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations, this chap has achieved what I (and others like me) can only dream of.

Comment: Amusing that rep is still shown in units of k even when it exceeds 1 million.

Comment: Congrats. You and I frequently answer the same MySQL questions, but your answers are almost always better than mine. On the rare occasions when I can find anything to criticize they're just minor points.

Comment: Congratulations @GordonLinoff. Your efforts will be appreciated  for years to come.

Comment: Considering the high volume of answers, do we know that he's personally writing them? Does he delegate the task to other people? It seems like this is all he does, yet he still manages to run a business and write books. Plus, not a single question. All of this *suggests* that he's not personally engaged. Of course, even if true, this may not matter to many, as the contributions are helpful nonetheless. But perhaps the accolades should be distributed fairly.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, Thank you for all your effort and love to the community.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin - Lots of Gordon's answers are posted within a few minutes of the question being asked and only take a couple of minutes to write so actual time taken writing answers could be less than 1hr per day even at 22.8 answers per day

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin he probably found the trick to create clones ;)

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin "..do we know that he's personally writing them?.." We can never really be sure with nobody. But I think it's possible. Maybe not me, but I can imagine people that write really good answers within a few minutes and do that for say one hour every day. That would make say 10 good answers every day or say a couple of tens of thousands of answers within 10 years. I certainly couldn't do it, but somebody really focused, knowledgeable and with an incredible stamina could probably pull it off. It doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: congrats Gordon Linoff but it will be better if you raise more helpful flags  will make site better to

Comment: @Gad - So, you think that Gordon is not doing quite enough already? :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan He does enough we all know but his flags are not at an interesting level like his answers

Comment: I don't think 0 questions is something one should be proud of. We all have the right to ask questions. And 71,839 answers - does he get paid for them? How does he make his living? Is he working full time for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Uri No, Gordon doesn't get paid for posting answers on Stack Overflow. No one here gets paid for posting anything. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400541) for some of the ways that Gordon makes his money: he writes books, works as a consultant, etc. I'm sure Gordon would ask a question if he had any that he couldn't answer by searching and attempting to solve the problem himself. There's no reason that he couldn't ask a question. However, asking questions is not a right (it is a privilege), nor is it an obligation.

Comment: I'm one of the thousands of fans of Gordon.  Thank you and congratulations.

Comment: So when is SO going to remove that *k* and start putting *M*  there ?

Comment: What's so awesome is he hasn't asked any questions! Only answers with this million feet...

Comment: @Uri He probably makes a decent living in his day job, on top of royalties from the books on SQL that he has published.

Comment: @Gad maybe not so much on the flags but it sure would be nice to see that downvote count way way higher...

Comment: @TylerH He [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252931/7228218) back in 2014 that he stopped downvoting altogether in favor of critical/helpful comments.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Regardless, it'd be nice to see that change, since comments don't directly curate content, but votes do :-)

Comment: @TylerH I agree. I also think that combining the downvote with a constructive comment is the way to go.

Comment: Go go [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) third millionaire (and first french!)

Comment: @GuerricP Thank you but don't hold your breath just yet. At my current (modest) pace, that won't be before early to mid-december.

Comment: @VonC I bet it will be before this weekend :D

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Indeed, it looks that way!

Comment: @VonC the rounding already does :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4imn.png

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' That is an optimistic rounding. Patience. 2 to 3 days now.

Comment: @GuerricP VonC reached 1 million rep two days ago. Take a look at [this featured post here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403218).

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy I know, I commented but my comment was deleted, not sure why. Thanks for notifying anyway!

Comment: I noticed that Gordon seems to have left the site, at least he has last anwered on 25th of september. Does anyone know what happened? After all his answers date back to 2012, so he has kept answering for the last 10 years ...

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald so weird! I hope he is OK.

Comment: Last seen "this week"

Answer (score 943):

I think only one answer is applicable here, really.

Welcome to the club, Gordon. It was getting lonely here.

Comment: What's next, the race to see who gets to 2 million first? Game on!

Comment: I know someone who wants to propose a new system, removing the daily cap and instead put a cap on posts. If I remember correctly, you'd be in the 2 million already if that was changed :) I'm pretty sure Gordon would be there too.

Comment: @cs95: I'm pretty sure Gordon will overtake me before either of us reaches 2 million.

Comment: It's interesting to muse on the different patterns of behavior and how they drive the various numbers behind the profiles.. And there are some very stark differences therein indeed

Comment: Quantity wins over quality on SO in the short-term, however, quality keeps on giving long after you're gone.

Comment: Wait, 1000 is not a round number, 1024 is

Comment: @Scratte More like 8 million if you ask me.

Comment: What has the club to offer? "Staff"-privilege, a never-empty and defective coffee machine and you have golden tissues with code snippets?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: Spare digits in case you run short.

Comment: But one standout diverging point of our SO millionaires: GordonLinoff has never asked a question. Jon Skeet did and good ones at that, an SO contributor on both sides!

Comment: @KevinB TLDR; rep = quantity, badges = quality is what I think you're getting at

Comment: I think "the next race" is to be more active in closing duplicates because there is too much focus on earning unicorn points instead of curating good content.

Comment: @Pac0 I disagree, the roundness in 1000 is three times as high as in 1024.

Comment: 1048576 is 100000000000000000000 which has 1 = 20 is 21 zeros. Even roundier than 1024 or 1000!

Comment: You predicted it correctly: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362217/2598770

Comment: @Scratte yes, or, if the `M` is single digit, include up to the ten thousand, so like this: `1.2M`

Comment: @cs95 I wanna challenge everyone to beat number of badges that Jon acquired.

Comment: @Scratte it should be like `1.20m` same as `339k`. 4 characters!

Comment: @cs95 it was more of a comment on comparing the usefulness of gordon's contributions compared to jons, in terms of how many people their contributions have helped and, more importantly, will help.

Answer (score 163):

I have been something of a silent cult follower of Gordon's over the years, and I have learned more about SQL from him than any other user on this site.  But, besides offering congratulations, I would like to focus on another obvious question which this milestone brings up: when will Gordon pass Jon Skeet and move into the #1 all-time position on the site?  Consider the following table of total annual rep from 2017 until the present year 2020:

```
year     | Gordon rep | Jon rep   | delta
2017     | 129,814    | 79,258    | 50,556
2018     | 135,289    | 79,997    | 55,292
2019     | 139,649    | 76,664    | 62,985
2020*    | 102,429    | 48,218    | 54,211
-------------------------------------------
all-time | 1,000,195  | 1,202,588 | 202,393

* year not yet completed
```

While Gordon's feat is certainly amazing, what is also very interesting is that at his current pace, Gordon will not eclipse Jon Skeet for at least another 3 years or so.

We can actually calculate, using Gordon and Jon's 2019 performance, when their rep levels will cross:

```
1000195 + x*139649 = 1202588 + x*76664
```

This gives `x = 3.21 years`, implying early November, 2023 as being the point when Gordon will eclipse Jon, assuming 2019 levels of performance.  This also assume that Jon won't "wake up" at some point and become more active again.

Comment: Another interesting thing to note is that by that time Gordon still won't be at 2 million reputation. 3 * 139,000 is 417,000, which means the total rep would add up to around 1,417,000.

Comment: @10Rep Yes...the only way it would take Gordon until 2 million to pass Jon would be if the latter becomes very active again at some point in the next 3 years, to "hold off" the former from passing.  Note also at this point that both Gordon and Jon probably cap off their daily rep of 20 upvotes without having to answer many questions.  They are both out for green checkmarks only at this point.

Comment: That's a linear extrapolation, but it looks like Gordon's annual rep is increasing slightly, and Jon's might be decreasing, so it will presumably be a bit sooner than your projection.

Comment: @SteveBennett I definitely agree. Jon's rep used to increase by **_a lot_**, and he still does earn. Just not as much. For instance, take March 12, 2019. Jon earned 816 reputation that day! Can you believe it?

Comment: Heh, I do kind of believe it. Once you have enough questions to your name you keep farming residual reputation from them. I get rep most days from this one question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210 I just need 50 questions like that. :)

Comment: @SteveBennett For a pleb like me that is impossible :D. I like focusing on curation and raising flags.

Comment: @10Rep _Everyone_ starts off on this site at a really low rep level.  It honestly took me like 2-3 years of struggling before my rep really took off.  Keep at it, and you will be over 100K faster than you can imagine `:-)`.

Comment: When do you get the mil @TimBiegeleisen? Your efforts have helped me out quite a few times.

Comment: @Beeblebrox at his current rate 7.8 yrs (250k @ 3yrs). This is a great answer Tim I hope it floats to the top. I also follow top people like Hans Passant, Eric Lippert & Jared Par - stuff you cannot learn from anyone else. You're right Gordon's depth of SQL is amazing. It's no secret the top 2 are both book authors, hopefully their reps do drive sales.

Comment: @SteveBennett The problem with upvotes from residual answers is the rep cap at 200/day. If you really want to play the game in the same league as John or Gordon, you need to shoot out enough answers to gain a considerable amount of accepts per day.

Comment: @Bergi Actually, for Jon, and also likely for Gordon, they get the 20 legacy upvotes each day automatically.  So for them, it is a game of going after green checkmarks.  Upvotes by themselves won't add much rep.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that's what I was trying to say. (I mean, on good days it's even a problem for me…)

Comment: Since you're doing stats: I've been watching Gordon's profile page since he had about 998,200. I wonder whether there were other people doing that as well, i.e., whether his profile page was viewed abnormally often the last few days. Can you (we?) query that?

Comment: @superbrain profile views are not available in SEDE, so you should use web archive or something similar to compare ranges of dates. In any case, I am sure there must have been some increase of views, and same will happen with [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) who is getting there quite fast (976K right now)

Comment: In this right moment, he's still answering the questions, 8 answers in less than 1 hour.

Comment: @Bergi: I definitely get 20 legacy upvotes on most days. When I was posting as "Daisy Shipton" for about 6 months, I very rarely posted new answers in the "Jon Skeet" account, but almost always still hit the rep cap.

Comment: Ho-ho, i also wrote kinda query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273627/who-is-next-jon-skeet

Comment: Well... ```365 days * 200 daily rep cap = 73000 reputation by upvotes```. So in that sense, Gordon is gaining rep from bounties and accepted answers (by posting new answers), while Jon is still hitting the daily cap everyday.

Comment: Delta is currently 146,421 - so probably still on track for that projection

Comment: Spanner in the works for the projection is that Gordon was last seen more than a month ago. Hope he is OK

Comment: @MartinSmith I emailed him a couple of times and got no response.  He is pretty high up at the New York Times and he may be engrossed with a large project at the moment.

Answer (score 78):

My congratulations to Gordon Linoff on achievement 1M reputation points on SO!

To do it, he had hard work behind this – he wrote more than 20 answers every single day for the last 8 years. Some users get a lot of reputation for doing nothing (earning reputation from popular questions or answers), but he got it in very small chunks (as compared to the amount of his answers).

His most popular answer has only 421 upvotes, which is very low (as compared to the most popular questions and answers upvotes). Whilst he is the second user with 1M reputation points on SO, he is the first user in answer count!

Thank you, Gordon Linoff, for your hard work, your time and your life!

### Some useful public info about Gordon Linoff

YouTube-video interview with him:
[**What it takes to be a good data modeler with Michael Berry and Gordon Linoff**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ly_yPwJxfo)

Article interview with him:
[**Database Guru Gordon Linoff Explains the Design Process and Data Mining**](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/gordon-linoff-on-the-design-process-and-data-mining/)

He is also the writer of [**useful SQL books**](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?field-author=Gordon%20S.%20Linoff)

Comment: Quite interesting to see more details of the man behind the gravatar. Thanks!

Comment: A short bio: http://www.data-miners.com/linoff.htm
He's an MIT alum.

Comment: Thanks and congrats! So far I only know Gordon Linoff's photo from the back of one of his books. Start cults are not my thing but I really appreciate his attitude. I noticed the interview on cloudways.com is tagged [PHP Interview]. Someone needs to tell the mods over there to fix it. :)

Answer (score 54):

Thank you Gordon for all the answers you've provided.

Beyond the million milestone, it is above anything, the help you gave to many of us, that lead us to a better understanding in the topics we were reaching for help.

Thank you again and waiting for the second million.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: Anyone can be a karma farmer. StackOverflow is a MMORPG not a forum or a help site.

Comment: @user234461 I completely disagree. The gamification of StackOverflow does not detract from the value of the forum or the answers given. As for Gordon specifically, it's been proven in other answers that he obtained his karma not in low effort, high reward ways, but exactly the opposite. He posted many legitimately helpful answers, showing that he isn't here to game the system, but instead provide real value.

Answer (score 46):

What I honestly find the most interesting aspect here ... that Gordon achieves this without going crazy.

Seriously. His reputation doesn't come from a few hundred questions that get crazy upvote counts. Nope, it is all about answering so many questions per day, and most of the answers being accepted, and upvoted a few times here and there. So, not only writing answers, but well received, **helpful** answers.

In other words: Gordon does the real hard work of growing reputation. That is damn hard work. Every day.

Thing is: during my years on SO and MSE; I had some periods when I tried to get there, too (well, on a smaller scale, not targeting a 1 million goal, or passing Jon Skeet). But I did pretty good, I have a few record months with some 5K or 6K reputation growth. And you know what: I am *not doing that any more, because I figured the negative effects on  the rest of my life.

But Gordon does that since 8 years. Which can only mean that he found a good way to integrate his "hobby" with his life. So, I think our community can be really grateful that Gordon found his purpose here, and that his dedication runs so deep that he can contribute on such a scale ... without burning out.

So, kudos to the master, may the upvotes be with you!

(and what is even more interesting: how can one find the time to learn **new** things, while already spending 26 hours per day explaining "known" things to others?!)

Comment: Good answer, and I would just add here that curiously Gordon has never asked any questions.  So, maybe he literally already knows so much about data that he has committed most of his free time to solving other people's problems `:-)`

Comment: Gordon is a master at SQL. He doesn't need to learn new things :D

Comment: "I figured the negative effects on the rest of my life" - This :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Or maybe he is just an alien who is logged in from a different dimension. From a place where a day has 50 hours, and maybe with so advanced technology that he can easily let us participate on some of the basics. For the good of all Kree, or something.

Comment: @GhostCat I want to steal/borrow " may the upvotes be with you!" from you :D

Comment: @Mithrandir You are welcome. Yeah, I admit: I am still a reputation collector, I just managed to be more ZEN inner peace about that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He [asked two](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8791/gordon-linoff?tab=questions) on DBA.

Comment: I like this....

Answer (score 27):

Congrats Gordon!

About a month back, I asked a **[Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140925/when-does-select-query-starts-with-a-with)**, and then Gordon came up with the answer. When I read his name, at first I wondered, was he the same guy who authored all those books that my friends and colleagues referred me to read for understanding some analytical concepts. And yes, it was him. Whoa!! It was a surprise.

And here he is helping out people daily and enjoying it. Keep up the good work

Comment: Touched by greatness! ;)

Answer (score 25):

Congratulations for reaching 1 million rep and thank you for gaving all of your knowledge *literally* without a break over the years to others, Gordon!

"*He only joined in 2012, so that's an average of ~22.8 answers per day, every day, for the last 3144 days.*"

If that is really true, I think your appropriate nick-name would be "*the machine*".

How is that even possible?! You must be a breathing lexicon indeed.

Thank you for all of your effort and willingness to spend time to help the community and other users in need. Users like Jon and you really make this community a better place.

Huge Thanks.

Comment: Although originally meant for Gordon, this para belongs also to high rep users like MartinSmith

Comment: I don't know if Gordon has a family, but I know that my Stack Exchange addiction chews into my career time,  family time, and sleep time. Not everyone has the time to post 20 answers per day every day.  Don't feel pressured to earn unicorn points.  Live your real life and just aim to be helpful when you volunteer on SE.

Comment: Must have a very understanding employer, that's all I can say.

Comment: @Lankymart: he probably has a huge SQL database with all the answers and just needs to write a SQL statement to find the answer to post here.

Comment: @Lankymart: as the founder of his own company, he can probably do that more easily than other employees

Comment: @ThomasWeller makes sense, couldn’t see any other viable option tbf.

Comment: [October 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation&sort=graph) looks like a break to me.

Comment: @superbrain What do you mean? He earned as usual.

Comment: @superbrain Yes, but nonetheless this is an average value. Which means he has equalized this by around 100 answers per day later on. :-)

Comment: @10Rep You can see a gap around October of 2013.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I just found your "*literally* without a break" probably misleading. Unless he didn't take a break there but there's a different explanation for the gap :-)

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I know. You have to find the exact place.

Answer (score 19):

Whenever I see a SQL question that I can answer, I would be in a hurry to submit my answer before Gordon does.

Mostly, I have failed to make it. But when I succeed, I was sure that this is Gordon's sleeping time.

Comment: True ....hahahahahah

Comment: Gordon: what does *sleeping time* mean?

Comment: this is why Gordon is toxic to the community. He answers within minutes and his answers are rushed and sometimes incorrect requiring an edit hours later. Of course after being corrected by a guy with 500 rep. He hoards the questions. Answers the most basic questions and leaves none for the little guys trying to earn a bit of rep. Gordon will never be a Jon Skeet

Comment: Well, that's another way to look at it. @MichaelZ.

Comment: @Sankar, I wouldn't be surprised if he had multiple people answering questions on his account. 22.8 answers a day every day. Sure it's possible to do on your own, but it would be quite time consuming. I'm sorry, but he's toxic to this community, specifically the SQL area.

Comment: He has twice as many questions as Jon Skeet. To me, that's a good indication of the quality of his answers. Sure he has some good answers and he knows his SQL stuff, but his behavior in answering questions within minutes with mistakes and then editing later is toxic. Another user could have came in and answered correctly the first time instead of having to comment on his incorrect answer.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I agree with you! Sometimes I left questions unanswered, even if I knew the answer, because Gordon will answer this in few seconds anyway.

Answer (score 17):

Again, congrats for reaching a million reputation. I personally cannot imagine getting a ***million*** reputation. It would be really hard for me to reach that.

What's really cool about this is the fact that you find ***so many*** questions to answer. That's the hard part about gaining reputation on SO. I cannot find questions to answer. That's half the deal. The other half is knowing enough to answer, of course.

So congratulations, again, and keep earning reputation as usual.

It'll be a fun competition to see who gets to 2 million first.

Comment: You multiplied your username by 200 in just 7 months. Just multiply that again in the upcoming months, and you should reach a million within a year.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks! It's really encouraging because I earned the mortarboard badge! But multiplying 100k in 7 months might be harder :D

Comment: It is simple 10 -- just write a page scraping bot with AI tuned to bring forward questions best suited to your skills.  Or you could use the tag search feature on the front page.

Answer (score 17):

What I do not see here is the astonishing amount of time he must spend on this. Let's say the average answer only takes five minutes. Some probably takes less but some requires more so five minutes is probably not outlandish. That would mean he spends as much as *two hours* every day on this site which is about a third of a normal job (which are only five days). *Wow*.

Answer (score 15):

Gordon, congrats on your achievement! Thanks so much for helping me with a performance issue I had related to Conditional Aggregation (`FILTER`), my app went from 18 minutes to **5 seconds** with your recommendation! It's right here: [SQL Performance Issues with Inner Selects in Postgres for tabulated report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532465/sql-performance-issues-with-inner-selects-in-postgres-for-tabulated-report) I personally appreciate your help! You saved me! :)

Answer (score 7):

Mr. Gordon Linoff is inspiration for many developers, I salute and thank him for all his answers and help on the platform.

Answer (score 7):

Congrats, Gordon! You are one of the few usernames I actually remember from the time I started programming for fun, way before it became my job (this has to be 5 years ago or so).

Answer (score 5):

You've earned the privilege to ask questions now :)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, Gordon. I remember your name because in (almost) 8 years on Stack Overflow I've only ever asked [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22557602/1640661) – and it was answered by you!

Thanks and best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations Gordon Linoff. Instead of restricting to leverage your knowledge to just your work, you have helped millions of developers across the world. You have done lots of good karma by continuously helping all the people struggling to fix problems.

I have seen Gordon Linoff even appreciating other answers, if they are good and suggesting the OP to accept the answer. Great inspiration for all developers. He goes extra mile to give credit for others answers to OP, if he finds them useful in his posts.

Best wishes for future millions.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I open Stack Overflow I see Gordon Linoff as the highest point achiever for a week. Kudos and congratulations, Gordon!! Inspiration for us!!

Answer (score 2):

So does he earn a new Privilege: "ability to collect a paycheck from SO"?

*- congrats*

Comment: No he does not, to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well done, well earned, and may the next million you earn be just as much of an adventure into broken code as the first!

I guess people on Stack Overflow aren't big fans of playful sarcasm...

Answer (score 1):

Congrats and thanks for all your help Gordon.  Your work has help thousands if not millions of IT professionals and students.

Answer (score 0):

Hearty cheers to the one of SQL's King of our time...Gordon Linoff

You're indeed an inspiration!!

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, Gordon. Like many others I have learned quite a bit about SQL from you. And if I manage to answer a SQL question before you do, it's because I learned the correct answer from you.

Not long until you will surpass the almighty Jon Skeet in reputation. I think THAT will be the day the world ends, and noone even predicted it.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, Gordon.  Records are made to be broken!  Go get him.